# Sharing CocoaPods-enabled Xcode project with team via SVN

Tags: xcode, svn, frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods

I have started using `CocoaPods` in an `Xcode project` that I am sharing with a non-technical team via `SVN`.

Before I commit the contents of my project folder, I wanted to ask whether they would also need `CocoaPods` installed in order to build and run the project?

Hopefully not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not add the Pods folder to your SVN repo then they will obviously have to have CocoaPods to build the project. Since otherwise none of your third party libraries will be included.

If you do add the Pods folder then the project will work just fine without CocoaPods installed.

Comment: Great - thank you; I'll give it a whirl now. Very kind.